# Calling ASCX control method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to call a method from my ascx control called BindTagCloud for the purpose of exporting it to a pdf file. How can I do that?

displaycloud.aspx:

```
<TagCloud:TagCloudControl ID="TagCloudControl1" runat="server" />
```

displaycloud.apsx.cs:

```
if (text.Length.Equals(0)) {

            --> BindTagCloud(); <--
            using (StringWriter sWriter = new StringWriter(strB)) {

                using (HtmlTextWriter htWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sWriter)) {

                    TagCloudControl1.RenderControl(htWriter);
                }
            } 
        }
```

Comment: Looks like you're calling the method correctly to me.

Comment: BindTagCloud() is a method in tagcloud.ascx.cs. I'm trying to call it in displaycloud.aspx.cs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply should add a public method `BindTagCloud` to the Code Behind file of the user control (`ascx` file). Then you can call the method by reference to your user control in your `aspx` page:

```
TagCloudControl1.BindTagCloud();
```

If you don't see the method in the IntelliSence window, rebuild the Web Site (in the main menu `Build` -> `Rebuild Web Site`)

Answer (score 1):

Override `Render` method for the user control and use the `HtmlTextWriter` there.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, then what you want is this:

```
TagCloudControl1.BindTagCloud();
```

Comment: I tried that, but apparently tagcloud.ascx does not contain a definition for BindTagCloud and no extension method accepting a first argument of type...In my tagcloud.ascx.cs, the method is declared as follows: public void BindTagCloud() {}